# JavaFX small collapsible pane?

Tags: java, javafx

I want a panel around two text fields that can be collapsed, similar to a TitledPane with no text. However the TitledPane uses too much vertical space so that it saves almost no space, as it reserves the space normally used for the title. Does JavaFX offer a really space-saving panel, lets say a rectangle with a triangle for collapsing?

Comment: Maybe you find something in controlsFx for your problem: http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/ (Maybe a popOver will do it for you)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such ui control in JavaFx apparently.  You must implement your own "collapsible pane" . It is possible to use [TreeView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/tree-view.htm) but I think it can only hold text values as child elements.